# Git-Repository inside Git-Repository (no submodule)

Tags: git

I want to use a gitrepository inside another gitrepository. I know there are submodules but I often read that they aren't that great. Right now I created a git repository, added .gitignore and only accepted some files via whitelist. Now I created another directory inside it and created with git init a new git repository inside the root repository. Right now it works without any problems...

I try to visualize the situation:

```
Root-Repository
- .git
- script.bat
- readme.md
- .gitignore (which ignores everything with * and whitelists !script.bat !readme.md !.gitignore)
- Directory
- - .git
- - .gitignore
- - other files...
```

What I want to achieve?
The Root-Repository should be the first repository every developer pulls. Than he runs the script (which git clones some projects, adds environment variables, build dependencies and so on..).

Is that okay or are there any downsides?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with git submodules yet, so I can't compare the two solutions.  I have done a similar thing, for similar reasons, with the difference that the root project is not a git repository.  My situation is something like this:

root_directory
  - git_repo_1
  - git_repo_2
  - ... (more repos)
  - project_build_repository.

The project build repository contains scripts for cloning the entire project and building (the entire project is built from the various subprojects, each of which can be built or used independantly).

There are a few downsides to doing something like this, and there is an additional downside to the approach you have taken which is not present in the variant I have done.

The general downside is whenever you have to apply an operation to all/multiple repositories, you have to manage this manually, or manage a script.  This leads to a variety of derivative problems -- you forget something, you have to maintain scripts, you deviate from the idiomatic way of doing things with git -- depending on how exactly you work around the root problem.

The disadvantage your approach has over mine is one of ambiguity.  A naive user might do a git command (status, push etc) and expect the submodules to be be handled correctly but they will not be.  This will compound the issues I discussed in the previous paragraph.

I don't necessarily recommend my approach (I will be evaluating the use of git submodule and comparing the tradeoffs in the near future), but in my approach the user does the following:

1. create a project dir.
2. in the project dir, clone the project_build_repo.
3. Run the initial clone script, which checks out all submodules in the correct paths.

In that case all the readme etc info goes in the project_build_repo.

Good luck.

Comment: For my case the general downside can be ignored because I can not think of a operation which needs to be done in all/multiple repositories (except pull/push ...). You are right concerning the naive user but our team is kinda small (5 people) and I think I can communicate that. Additionally the git-repositories inside the root-git-repositories are vs 2013 projects and the push pull stuff is done inside the ide. The ide is configured to use root/project/ and not root/.